# Java: Can the mocked code be placed in test folder?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

For the Java projects, we have the best practice of segregating functional code in to "main" folder and unit test code in to "test" folder.

As part of testing, we also create mock provider objects, typically where integration/external calls are involved. My focus is about objects that are almost like real providers but with limited functionality and use fixed / hard coded data. Not about using Mickito-like frameworks.

These objects facilitate testing but have no real use in application. Can we place these objects in "test" folder instead of "main"? This will also avoid extra step of excluding such classes from the build process.

Please let me know, if there are any guidelines for this.

Comment: Where I come from, we always place stubs, mocks and all kinds of auxiliary classes used only in test in the test or unittest (or systemtest or integrationtest) folder. After all, in my understanding this is the main point in having separate test folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right. These "stub" objects (as opposed to mocks) should be placed in the test source root.

There is a case where you would place them in a main folder and that is if you want to share the stubs across multiple modules. If you need to do this, then the stubs should be moved to the main source root of their own separate module. This module can then be made a "test" dependency (maven) or a "testCompile" dependency (gradle) which still keeps it separate from production code (even though it's in a main folder).

Sometimes it is also useful to write tests for your stubs if they get a bit complicated, to ensure that they replicate the behaviour of the real thing accurately. This is another situation when you might want to move them to the main source root of another module.

But still in general they should not be in the same source root as production code. If nothing else they will mess up your code coverage statistics!

Comment: At this moment, the purpose of these mocked objects are for unit test purposes only. I believe they should be in test folder.